# Is there a plugin that lets users request an account on the site?

Tags: plugins, user-access, account

Is there a Wordpress plugin that lets users fill in a form to request an account that then has to be cleared/activated by an admin for the user to get access?

Comment: maybe [new user approve](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/new-user-approve/)

Answer (score 3):

Under "Settings > General" - check the box that says "Anyone can register."

After that, the registration page is publicly available at http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=register

As [Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo) suggested, after enabling registration, the [New User Approve](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/new-user-approve/) plugin may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is built into WordPress, as [GavinR](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2001/gavinr) mentioned [in his answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25959/is-there-a-plugin-that-lets-users-request-an-account-on-the-site/26108#26108), however this requires the user to see pieces of the admin interface. To get around this on a site I deployed about a year ago, I used the [Theme My Login plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/), which allows the signup, login, and personal preferences for each user to be inside of your site's front-end theme instead of forwarding to the admin. It also adds additional features.

Once you've changed your preferences in [`Settings -> General`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen) so that the `Anyone can register` checkbox is checked, the Theme My Login plugin takes over. It [allows admins to prevent new users from logging in until they're approved](http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/user-moderation/), and [allows you to redirect users to a specific page once they've logged in](http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/custom-redirection/).

There's a great overview of the plugin's functionality on its [plugin page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/), and [more information in its documentation](http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/).